# Any editor/IDE that supports or could be hacked to support viewing diffs live while editing?

Tags: vim, emacs, editor, diff

Is there any editor/IDE that provides a live view of differences (probably using `diff`) while I am editing a file.  The ideal setting would be when I open a file for editing in such a diff-mode, the file is buffered in two independent panes (but put side by side), so that when I edit the contents of one, the differences of the two are highlighted for me.

Comment: You've already asked about automating Vim's `:diffupdate`; what's missing from `vimdiff` for you?!

Comment: There are two drawbacks of `vimdiff`: 1. it cannot buffer the same file independently to allow a `diff` comparison.  Of course, this can be solved by automatically making a temporary copy of the file; 2. Inside `vimdiff`, inline editing (inserting or deleting) could not trigger `diff` to recalculate the difference, one has to do it manually by executing `:diffupdate`.  I want this recalculation to be automated when I exit the *INSERT* mode and enter the *NORMAL* mode.

Comment: +1 the question. because I see finally, the two guys: vim and emacs are sitting together in tags row, and watching us to post answer.

Comment: @plmday vim you could create `au` for event InsertEnter/InsertLeave. you can call diffupdate there.

Comment: @Kent, exactly.  Actually I have found the [perfect solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72205/live-diff-mode-editing-in-vim) is to catch the events `CursorMoved` and `CursorMovedI`.

Answer (score 3):

There doesn't seem to be an existing Emacs mode to do exactly what you want, but a cursory googling turned up [this](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EdiffMode) and [this](http://jclark.org/weblog/2005/06/10/diffbuffer/).

From the second one (with mildly fixed formatting):

```
(defun diff-buffer-against-file (context)
    "diff the current [edited] buffer and the file of the same name"
    (interactive "P")
    (let (($file buffer-file-name)
          ($tempFile "/tmp/emacs.diff")
          ($tempBuffer "emacs.diff"))
        (delete-other-windows)
        (push-mark (point) t)
        (generate-new-buffer $tempFile)
        (copy-to-buffer $tempBuffer (point-min) (point-max))
        (set-buffer $tempBuffer)
        (write-file $tempFile)
        (shell-command (concat (if context "diff -c " "diff ") $file " " $tempFile))
        (kill-buffer $tempFile)
        (pop-mark)))

(global-set-key "\C-cd" 'diff-buffer-against-file)
```

The operation looks a bit too intense to bind to a [change hook](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Change-Hooks.html#Change-Hooks), but there's nothing preventing you from doing so if you're into that sort of thing.

**Edit:** Stefan points out that `diff-buffer-with-file` exists, and has the behavior you're looking for (it takes a buffer, and `diff`s that buffer with its file, showing that output in an unfocused temporary buffer), so you don't even need to define the above. I did try it though, and the naive

```
(defun diff-current (start end len) (diff-buffer-with-file (current-buffer)))
(add-hook 'after-change-functions 'diff-current)
```

makes editing too uncomfortable for my tastes. You'll probably want to follow Stefan's suggestion and use a timeout instead of `diff`ing immediately on every change.

Comment: Emacs already provides `diff-buffer-with-file`, no need to write it by hand any more.  It would probably be OK to add such a function to a timer (it wouldn't be refreshed immediately, but soon).

Comment: It is nice to see that Emacs also provides a partial solution, which may be hacked as you suggested to a full solution.